# How to forget wifi which it does not aviable right now?

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I want to forget wifi network with this code sample but it cannot forget wifi which not in range.

```
private void removeNetwork(WifiManager wifiManager, WifiConfiguration wc) {
        if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) enableWifi();
        int id = wifiManager.addNetwork(wc);
        wifiManager.enableNetwork(id, true);
        wifiManager.removeNetwork(id);
        wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
    }
```

How I can remove network?

**UPD1:**

I'm talking about the WIFI information which was added by myself.

```
private void addNetwork(WifiManager wifiManager, WifiConfiguration wc) {
    if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) enableWifi();
    int id = wifiManager.addNetwork(wc);
    wifiManager.disconnect();
    wifiManager.enableNetwork(id, true);
    wifiManager.reconnect();
    wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
}
```

Comment: Well, the docs say that we are not allowed to remove a network created by other apps. This might be the only reason for this to fail.

Comment: @Jay I have updated question, please check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this code example and code work well, something wrong with your implementation of this code.

It is depend of wifi configuration and this is my work example.

```
private void WPA(String networkSSID, String networkPass, WifiManager wifiManager, String command) {
        WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();
        wc.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
        wc.preSharedKey = "\"" + networkPass + "\"";
        wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
        wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
        wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
        wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
        wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
        wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
        wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
        if (command.equals("add")) {
            addNetwork(wifiManager, wc);
        }else  if (command.equals("remove")) {
            removeNetwork(wifiManager,wc);
        }
    }
```